# how to stop or exit protractor from executing the other specifications with wrong credentials

Tags: angular, selenium, jasmine, protractor, e2e-testing

`

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { LoginComponent } from './../login/login.component';
import { browser, by, element } from 'protractor';
import { error } from '@angular/compiler/src/util';
import { CATCH_ERROR_VAR } from '@angular/compiler/src/output/abstract_emitter';

describe('login page',  function () {
  browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
  browser.driver.get('http://localhost:4200/login/');
  require('jasmine-bail-fast');

  it('should sign in',  function () {
    // Find page elements
    var  userNameField  =  browser.driver.findElement(by.id('email_id'));
    var  userPassField  =  browser.driver.findElement(by.id('pass'));
    var  userLoginBtn  =  browser.driver.findElement(by.css('#blog_1 > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > form > div.formFooter.text-center > button'));
    // Fill input fields
    userNameField.sendKeys('protrya@yopmail.com');
    userPassField.sendKeys('12345678');
    // Click to sign in - waiting for Angular as it is manually bootstrapped.
    userLoginBtn.click().then(() => {
      expect(userNameField.getAttribute('value')).toEqual('protrya@yopmail.com');
      expect(userPassField.getAttribute('value')).toEqual('12345678');
    })
    return  browser.driver.wait(function () {

      return  browser.driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function (url) {
        return  /dashboard/.test(url);
      });
    },  10000).then(
      function () {

        console.log('success');
      },
      function () {
        console.log('invalid');
        process.exit();

      });

  });
});
```

`
I am facing a problem in protractor testing. actually my application contains around 5 to 6 specifications and the first specification is login. If my login credentials are right it has to execute the other specifications and this is completely working fine.so, I am facing a problem when login credentials are wrong. With wrong login credentials it should not execute the other specifications. So how can I achieve this..?

In my code I have used process.exit(1), so currently its checking the login credentials and the other specifications are not executed, where as in console I'm getting an error saying "process exit with error code 1".

Comment: How about if you use `function(err){
           throw new Error('Error occurred!'); 
        });` instead of exit using process. What is the outcome?

Comment: But its giving specification itself failed, but here specification is not wrong its just checking wrong credentials. how can i achieve this without failing first specification@eduPeeth

Comment: You don't want to log it as a failure? Is it?

Comment: Yes, I need like, specification passed with error message

Comment: What if you use `process.exit()` instead of `process.exit(1);` ?

Comment: [18:46:29] E/launcher - BUG: launcher exited with 1 tasks remaining.. this is what i am getting when i used process.exit(); @eduPeeth

Comment: How are your success and invalid functions get called?

Comment: Also,  Can you paste this code please instead of screen shot?

Comment: The login button itself contains the logic. When the credentials are matching it navigates to the next page then the success message prints on the console else invalid message @eduPeeth

Comment: You kind of resolve the promise after the click and then put two asserts on username and password and then return some url. I am not sure how your set time out is calling success and invalid. How about if you put the code till button click in try and catch the exception but don't throw anything just console a message.

Comment: i have shared my code @eduPeeth

Comment: I pasted something. Please try and let me know if any luck. I removed the return statements just for simplicity for now.

Comment: Yeah I tried with your code, But still it is executing other specifications

Answer (score 0):

### For your consideration

A couple of things to consider:

- You are importing Angular unit test libs and components when you just
  need the Protractor dependency.
- It also looks like you are turning off wait for Angular. Protractor waits for Angular to become stable before moving to the next promise. If this is as desired, you'll need to come up with your own wait method.

### Code snippet to skip tests if one fails:

I am writing the following with the idea that you should eventually turn off the control flow. This will eventually need to happen when the control flow goes away.

```
describe('a workflow',  () => {
  // keep track of a local variable for tests after logging in.
  // assuming all tests for this workflow is in the same file
  let skipTest = false; // bool

  describe('logging in', () => {    

    it('should log in', async() => {
      try {
        await browser.get('http://localhost:4200/login/');

        let userNameField = element(by.id('email_id'));
        let userPassField = element(by.id('pass'));
        let userLoginBtn = element(by.css(
            '#blog_1 > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > form >' + 
            'div.formFooter.text-center > button'));

        // Fill input fields
        await userNameField.sendKeys('protrya@yopmail.com');
        await userPassField.sendKeys('12345678');

        // Click to sign in - waiting for Angular as it is manually bootstrapped.
        await userLoginBtn.click();

        expect(await userNameField.getAttribute('value'))
            .toEqual('protrya@yopmail.com');
        expect(await userPassField.getAttribute('value')).toEqual('12345678');
      } catch (err) {
        skipTest = true;
      }
    });
  });

  // Personal preference to have nested describe blocks to organize your
  // information.
  describe('some other action', () => {
    it('should do something else', (done) => {
      // check the skip test variable. if it is set to true, we should
      // fail the test and give the reason. In this case, we are just
      // showing that the log in failed. This is under the assumption
      // that if you cannot login, you should fail the rest of the workflow.
      if (skipTest) {
        done.fail('did not log in, skipping test "should do something else"');
      }
      // actual test logic

      // Still required to call done() so the jasmine test knows to stop
      // the test and not timeout.
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: i tried with the above code, still i'm facing the same problem. In my conf.js file i have 2 spec file which are login and dashboard. once my credentials are wrong it should not navigate to dashboard spec file. so my question here is how to stop the protractor to stop executing the dashboard spec file when wrong credentials and vice-versa.@cnishina

Comment: The problem you have is in organization of the tests, you can have 2 tests: first try to login with wrong credentials and validate that user is not logged in , second login with correct credentials and validate that use successfully logins.

Comment: I would keep a workflow to one file. If you are logging in with a beforeAll, you should have a logout in an afterAll. If you need to log in for each test, I would separate it out into common methods.